# Floor heating system increased resistance

Tags: electrical

I have a Danfoss floor heating system installed ( properly, qualified electrician) and now after concrete and tiles have been set up my Ohmmeter shows a triple value that it should be. Can someone answer why electrical resistance has increased dramatically (proper measurement and tools have been used, by a qualified person)? Thank you in advance...

Comment: because now it is hot?

Comment: it's not powered on, ohm reading is too high

Comment: Connected in series? Do you have the connection layout?

Comment: Yes, and no I don't have connection layout

Comment: Where did you get your reference of what it "should be?" Does this come from Danfoss, directly, for your specific installation? If so, what are their stated conditions for measurement? (If performed by a qualified person who is not you, then shouldn't you put that person in touch with Danfoss, directly, to resolve this question?) I guess I'm a little confused about why you think someone here can better resolve this for you when you have qualified people installing and qualified people measuring. This seems like a time for putting heads together at your end. Not so much, here.

Comment: On the one had, we can only speculate wildly with the information you provided. On the other hand, it seems likely that your system consists of 3 heater elements connected electrically in parallel, and 2 of them have become disconnected. If you turn the system on, does only 1/3 of the floor warm up?

Comment: Electrician is due to meet their salesman tomorrow; Sorry for my bad explanation, electrician installed everything by their standards and it worked yesterday(final test was done app 4 hours after ceramic tiles where glued), this night it's not working ( or not heating properly after 2 hours waiting) and the only difference was in ohm value which was 3 times bigger than yesterday..